# What are the differences between these 업소, 작업, 근무, 기업, 업체, 영업 and 사업

Tags: vocabulary

I understand 업소 as the place of the work, 근무 as office work, and 작업 as work that is related more to the physical work.
The similarities between 기업, 업체, 영업 and 사업 confuses me
Any example provided will be great :)
감사합니다!

Answer (score 2):

## Dictionary definitions

- **작업**: 일정한 목적과 계획 아래 하는 일.
- **근무**: 직장에 적을 두고 직무에 종사함.
- **사업**: 어떤 일을 일정한 목적과 계획을 가지고 짜임새 있게 지속적으로 경영함. 또는 그 일.
- **영업**: 영리를 목적으로 하는 사업. 또는 그런 행위.
- **업소**: 사업을 벌이고 있는 장소.
- **기업**: 영리<sub>營利</sub>를 얻기 위하여 재화나 용역을 생산하고 판매하는 조직체.
- **회사**: 상행위 또는 그 밖의 영리 행위를 목적으로 하는 사단 법인. 주식회사, 유한 회사, 합자 회사, 합명 회사의 네 가지가 있다.
- **업체**: 사업이나 기업의 주체.
- **업계**: 같은 산업이나 상업에 종사하는 사람들의 활동 분야.

---

## My explanation

### What you do

- **작업**: a specific **task** done with a purpose and a plan, not necessarily physical, not necessarily moneymaking, possibly personal. → the verb’s “**작업하다**.”

  - “데이터 백업 **작업**” — “a data backup **task**”
  - “윈도우즈 **작업** 관리자” — “*Windows* **task** manager”
  - “수리 **작업**” — “repair **work**”
- **근무**: **working as an employee**, not necessarily office work. → the verb’s “**근무하다**.”

  - “그분은 다른 회사에서 **근무**하십니다.” — “He’s **work**ing for another company.”
- **사업**: a commercial operation; an operation that makes money; a **business**, nonprofit or not. → the verb’s “**사업하다**.”

  - “개인 **사업**자” — “an *individual **business*** conducted by a human being, that is not a *legal person*.”
- **영업**: a **business conducted primarily to make a profit, usually by selling stuff**; selling stuff and making money for you to rake in. → the verb’s “**영업하다**.”

  - “**영업** 끝났습니다.” — “We’re closed.”
  - “정상 **영업** 합니다.” — “We’re open.”
  - “**영업** 비밀” — “trade secret”

### Places and legal entities

- **업소**: a specific place (not an *area*) where a business is actually performed; **a place of business**.

  - I ordered sandwiches today and got a can of Pepsi as well. It’s on my desk and it says “**업소**용<sub>用</sub>” — “for commercial use,” or literally, “intended to be consumed at **a place of business**.” Pepsi sold to restaurants is cheaper than store-bought Pepsi.
- **기업**: **a company**; an enterprise; a legal entity, not necessarily a *legal person*, representing *an association of people*.

  - “공**기업**” — “a state-owned **enterprise**”
  - “**기업**용 소프트웨어” — “**enterprise** software”
  - “일인 **기업**” — “a one-person **company**”
- **회사**: **a corporation**; a company that is a *legal person*; also means “**an office**.”

  - “유한 **회사**” — “a limited **company**”
  - “비가 오기 시작했는데 우산을 **회사**에 두고 왔네요.” — “It’s started raining and I left my umbrella at **the office**.”
  - “그분은 다른 **회사**에서 근무하십니다.” — “He’s working for another **company**.”
- **업체**: **a legally registered entity running a business**, that is not a *human being* and not necessarily a *legal person*, including a *company* and an *individual business*.

  - “식품 **업체**” — “Food **company**”

### Others

- **업계**: **the trade**; an industry; the people engaged in a particular area of business; a particular branch of commercial activity.

  - “철강 **업계**가 전에 없는 호경기를 누리고 있다.” — “The steel **industry** is booming like never before.”

---

### Useful Hanja’s

- “**업**<sub>業</sub>”: business; operation.
- “**-체**<sub>體</sub>”: body; entity; organization.
- “**-계**<sub>界</sub>”: field; branch.
- “**-소**<sub>所</sub>”: place.